# How to monitor a web application using WSO2 BAM?

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-bam

I have a web application (java) and I want to monitor it from the BAM, everything I have done so far is explained in this link:

[Setting up Message Tracer Filter to a web application](http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Setting+up+Message+Tracer+Filter+to+a+web+application)

But I do not know how to see the result of this in the BAM, ie how can I see in the BAM, the data being sent by the application?

Comment: You will want to include more information, including snippets from whatever configuration file(s) you edited in your attempt to get the BAM monitoring working.

Answer (score 1):

All the data sent from data agents to BAM are stored in Cassandra database. In BAM you will see the menu item, "Cassandra Explorer". GO there and add the localhost:9160 as the url, admin/admin as username/password. You will see the content of Cassandra database. Go to "EVENT_KS" column family and explore the column family related to the data received from data agents. I do not know the name of the column family but you can explore each of them and see which one is the related one.

Comment: BAM not provide some UI in the Dashboard to monitor this web application activity?

Comment: Yes. It is available here. http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Activity+Monitoring+Dashboard

Comment: ok so if I want to display this information in some tipe of graphic I need to use jaggery framework right? can you suggest a tutorial to do that?

Comment: Yes. You can go through the sample codes in http://jaggeryjs.org/samples.jag to familiar with Jaggery. It is simply server side JavaScript.